# Create Trigger to update the record that was newly inserted on PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, triggers

I want the trigger to fire when a new record is inserted, and update that newly inserted record to add a current date and time, need help please be kind still new here :(

here's my code:

FUNCTION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.func_update_date_sync()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.rptowner SET date_sync = NOW()
        WHERE dbo.rptowner.owner_no = (SELECT MAX(dbo.rptowner.owner_no) FROM dbo.rptowner);
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$
;
```

TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg__update_date_sync 
AFTER INSERT
ON dbo.rptowner FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE dbo.func_update_date_sync()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WHERE condition is needlessly complicated (and slow) as you could replace it with `where owner_no = new.owner_no` as you have full access to the inserted (or updated) row in the trigger.

However, there is no need for a costly UPDATE statement. Use a `BEFORE` trigger, and *assign* the values to the fields in the new record:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.func_update_date_sync()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  new.date_sync := now();
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
;
```

And declare the trigger as a BEFORE trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg__update_date_sync 
  BEFORE INSERT ON dbo.rptowner 
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE dbo.func_update_date_sync()
```

---

As a side note: Most people are not aware that `now()` [is a synonym](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) for `transaction_timestamp()`. So all rows inserted or updated in a single transaction will have exactly the same value for `date_sync`. If that is OK for you, then everything is fine. If you expect each row to have a (slightly) different timestamp, you should use `clock_timestamp()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a timestamp when a new record is created you can use `NOW()` as default value. There is no need to use a trigger.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.rptowner ALTER COLUMN date_sync SET DEFAULT NOW();
```